# Trace in finite Fields

Tags: finite-fields, trace

(1) In $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ with odd n it should be shown that half of the Trace values are 0 and the other part is 1 with help of the additivity of the Trace.
(2) Now n shall be even. Now the distribution of the Trace values of the elements is the same as (1). For the proof it should be used that if n is even $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ contains a sub field which is isomorph to n $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$

Has anybody an idea how to start ?

Comment: Can you write down a formula for the trace?

Comment: What's wrong with the usual argument? The trace is a polynomial of degree $2^{n-1}$, so it cannot have more than $2^{n-1}$ zeros. The trace is an additive homomorphism from $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}\to\Bbb{F}_2$, so it must have at least $2^{n-1}$ zeros (either use [the first homomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) or rank-nullity). The parity of $n$ is never used here.

Comment: In my opinion trying to use the intermediate field $\Bbb{F}_4$ as a stepping stone just complicates matters. Mind you, that is a useful stepping stone for many an argument (e.g. the formula for solutions of a quadratic using the half-trace, when $n\equiv2\pmod4$, or when the argument needs that ever useful cubic root of unity), but this is not one of them.

Comment: If I would use an intermediate field, i would use the intermediate field $\mathbb F_{2^{(n/2)}}$, since the trace map $\mathbb F_{2^n} \to \mathbb F_{2^{(n/2)}}$ is non-vanishing, because there are no irreducibles of the form $X^2+a$ in finite fields of characteristic $2$. So by induction we obtain that the trace $$\mathbb F_{2^n} \to \mathbb F_{2^{(n/2)}} \to \mathbb F_{2}$$ is surjective as the composition of two surjective maps.

Comment: @Jyrki: thank you very much. I tried to use the rank nullity: dim (Im(Trace) + dim (Ker( Trace) = dim F2^n => 2 + dim (Ker(Trace))= 2^n => ker = 2^(n-1); ker is the neutral elemente of Trace and therefore 0; is this the way to proove